How does covenant theology handle the priestly covenant?
Covenant theology generally regards God's covenants with Noah, Abraham, Moses, David, and the new covenant as the primary divine covenants. The priestly covenant Numbers 25 seems to go largely ignored. My knowledge comes mostly from the lectures of the covenant theology course of Reformed Theological Seminary (listening online, not attending) and it isn't mentioned. All that I found is a footnote in The Christ Of The Covenants saying the priestly covenant is just considered an extension of the Mosaic. Is there anything more to this or is the topic just not discussed?

This question prompted me to pull out two books on Covenant theology, as explained by Reformed theologians. One was written in 2013 (The Book of the Covenant, B.N. Howard), the other in 2017 (Sacred Bond - Covenant Theology Explored, Brown & Keele, second edition). Right enough, there seemed to be nothing in them about the special covenant detailed in Numbers chapter 25.
Then I looked out a book which rejects the 'Covenant theology' of Reformed theologians. But it did go into details about Numbers chapter 25! And after re-reading it, the clue as to why Reformed Covenant theology does not seem to mention this particular covenant seemed to be there.
The chapter is headed, "Phinehas' Account" and deals with Psalm 106:30-31 and Job 9:2 in relation to Numbers 25:10-13. There is detailed the actions of one priest called Phinehas, who stayed the plague on Israel. The book takes six pages to explain why God made an everlasting covenant of priesthood, and the prophetic significance of that. I cannot do justice to the explanation with snippets, so the chapter itself needs to be read. The 2012 book can be downloaded for free (and without registration) at http://www.belmontpublications.co.uk  Look for the book "Righteousness" and go to pages 63 to 69. The start of that section says:

"Psalm 106:30,31  Then stood up Phinehas and executed judgment: and so
the plague was stayed. And that was counted unto him for righteousness
unto all generations for evermore." And these words begin to tell us
the answer to Job's question. How? How shall man be just with God?
[Job 9:2]... Through this "executed judgment" came an "accounted
righteousness", Psalm 106:30.
'And the Lord spake unto Moses, saying, Phinehas, the son of Eleazar,
the son of Aaron the priest, hath turned my wrath away from the
children of Israel. Wherefore say, Behold I give unto him my covenant
of peace. And he shall have it, and his seed after him. Even the
covenant of an everlasting priesthood. Because he made a cover -
kaphar - for the children of Israel.' Numbers 25:10-13.

The book's gentle unfolding of what was, back then, a dreadful event in Israel, speaks profoundly to us today. But, as I said, the author does not agree with Reformed Covenant theology.
